# React native returns Promise instead of value Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to fetch multiple documents from Firestore basen on an array of IDs (yummed) which are saved in my users collection. I first fetch the IDs and then I have a map function which finds each document from the recipes collection and assigns it to variable data. The problem is that instead of getting just the result for each ID, I get a Promise for each of the IDs. How can I fix this in order to get just the data?

```
export const yummedRecipesFetch = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection(`users`).doc(currentUser.uid)
            .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                var data = doc.data().yummed.map(function (recipeId) {
                    return firebase.firestore().collection(`recipes`).doc(recipeId).get().then(function(doc) {
                        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()};
                    })                    
                })
                console.log(data)
                dispatch({ type: YUMMED_RECIPES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: data })
            });
    };
};
```

Comment: You can't just get the data, it's asynchronous. You can however use `Promise.all` to get a promise for an array of data.

Comment: Thanks so much @Bergi, used Promise.all and .then(function(values){...})
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: yeah sorry about that , changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggestion above Promise.all

```
export const yummedRecipesFetch = () => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection(`users`).doc(currentUser.uid)
            .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
                var data = doc.data().yummed.map(function (recipeId) {
                    return firebase.firestore().collection(`recipes`).doc(recipeId).get().then(function(doc) {
                        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data()};
                    })                    
                })
                Promise.all( data).then(function(values) {
                    dispatch({ type: YUMMED_RECIPES_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: values })
                })
            });
    };
};
```